# Should we kill all the [character]s?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just noticed that we have a [character](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag, apparently for questions which are specifically about a particular character or characters in a work of literature.

**Is this tag useful, or should we burninate it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take the George R R Martin approach here:

### Let's kill the [character](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character)s.

- [character](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) wouldn't work as the sole tag on a question, which means it's probably a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and therefore undesirable according to SE central policy.
- The purpose of tags is supposed to be for experts in a given subject to find questions to answer on that subject, but there are obviously no experts on *characters* in general.
- It doesn't help searchability, since no-one is going to be interested in looking for all of the questions about all characters in all works of literature.
- Most questions with this tag are about a specific character in a specific book, so why not just tag them with the tags for that book/series/author? There's no need to further point out "hey, this question is just about one character".
- The tag hasn't been used consistently so far, which suggests it probably won't be in the future either. [Many](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1915/17) [existing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1901/17) [questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1818/17) [about](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1810/17) [characters](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1050/17) [don't](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/804/17) [have](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/779/17) [the](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/769/17) [character](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag. If we're going to use it to classify questions but most of the questions that 'deserve' it don't have it, then the tag seems pretty useless.

<sub><sub>Some of the above points are taken from [the corresponding M&TV meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/27759); I think they apply equally well here.</sub></sub>

Comment: I just removed the tag from all questions. If it gets created again I'll ask SE to burn it.

Comment: @Hamlet Well, that was quick. There isn't really a consensus on this meta post yet.

Comment: Isn't there a mod option to nuke the tag without manually editing? I didn't find anything.

Comment: Given that the character tag could be applied to at least 50% of the questions on the site, your arguments in the meta post, and our prior discussions about tags, I didn't see this suggestion as anything other than routine. Maybe I was wrong. @Mithrandir I'm 95% sure that's something we have to ask the CMs for help for.

Comment: @Mithrandir Oh, if only ...

Comment: And also, there's a [character-analysis tag], so if people were upset about the loss of the [characters] tag they could use that instead.

Comment: @Hamlet I wonder if that one should go too, for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: @Randal'Thor make a meta post? For that tag, I would wait for a consensus, because it seems more controversial.

Comment: @Hamlet I could simply edit this meta post, since IMO exactly the same reasons apply for burninating both tags. Of course then the [tag:status-completed] tag would have to be removed, at least for a while ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor just make a new question and copy your answer, that seems least confusing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I _don't_ think [character-analysis] is _necessarily_ the same as [characters] here. I do think it's being used ambiguously, but I think there are ways to define [character-analysis] such that it's a useful informative tag about the topic of a post. Whether it's too broad so as to be not useful is another question, though.

Comment: @Hamlet [Done](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/568/17).

Comment: @Emrakul I see your point, and I'm not so strongly against the [tag:character-analysis] tag as against the [tag:characters] one. But I've still posted an answer more or less the same as this one to argue for the abolition of [tag:character-analysis]. Feel free to post a contradictory answer if you think that tag is worth keeping.