# Do we need a [character-analysis] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [character-analysis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis) tag, whose tag wiki excerpt reads as follows:

> For questions about how characters act or are constructed by authors.

**Is this tag useful, or should we burninate it?**

<sub><sub>This is related to, but separate from, my previous post [Should we kill all the [character]s?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/565/17) I considered putting both in one, but Hamlet♦ [suggested](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/565/should-we-kill-all-the-characters#comment2020_566) that I make a new Q&A instead.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a little early to decide this one way or another. Unlike the [character](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) tag, this tag actually *does* have useful meaning - it's just not clear yet how it's being used.

Since we don't really know what it means in practice on the site yet (only fifteen questions have used it), it's hard to say anything about whether it's a good tag to keep. "Character analysis" certainly *is* a topic in literature, at a minimum, which means it has the potential to describe a valid category of question.

If, after discussion and watching how it's used, we still come to the conclusion that it's ambiguous/unclear/not meaningful or helpful, then I'd be in favor of burninating it. But I don't think we're at that point quite yet.